# Resolving File Name Permutations

Tags: c#, permutation

I am attempting to import a .CSV file into my database which is a table export from an image management system.  This system allows end-users to take images and (sometimes) split them into multiple images. There is a column in this report that signifies the file name of the image that I am tracking. If items are split in the image management system, the file name receives an underscore ("_") on the report.  The previous file name is not kept.  The way the items can possibly exist on the CSV are shown below:

```
Report 1 @ 8:00AM:  ABC.PNG

Report 2 @ 8:30AM:  ABC_1.PNG
                    ABC_2.PNG 

 Report 3 @ 9:00AM: ABC_1_1.PNG 
                    ABC_1_2.PNG
                    ABC_2_1.PNG
                    ABC_2_2.PNG 

Report 4 @ 9:30AM   ABC_1_1_1.PNG
                    ABC_1_1_2.PNG
                    ABC_1_2.PNG
                    ABC_2_1.PNG
                    ABC_2_2.PNG
```

I am importing each file name into its own record.  When an item is split, I would like to identify the previous version and update the original record, then add the new split record into my database.  The key to knowing if an item is split is locating an underscore ("_").

I am not sure what I should do to recreate previous child names, I have to test every previous iteration of the file name to see if it exists.  My problem is interpreting the current state of the file name and rebuilding all previous possibilities.  I do not need the original name, only the first possible split name up until the current name.  The code below shows kind of what I am getting at, but I am not sure how to do this cleanly.

```
String[] splitName = theStringToSplit.Split('_');

for (int i = 1; i < splitName.Length - 1; i++)
{
    //should concat everything between 0 and i, not just 0 and I
    //not sure if this is the best way or what I should do

    MessageBox.Show(splitName[0] + "_" + splitName[i] + ".PNG");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is part of string.
So `string.Join()` might help you joining an array to a delimited string:
It also contains a parameter start index and number of items to use.

```
string[] s = new string[] { "2", "a", "b" };
string joined = string.Join("_", s, 0 ,3);

// joined will be "2_a_b"
```

Maybe you are using the wrong tool for you problem. If you want to keep the last "_", you may want to use `LastIndexOf()` or even Regular Expressions. Anyways: You should not unnecessarily rip of names and re-glue them. If done, do it cultrue invariant and not culture specific (there might be different interpretations of "-" or the low letter of "I".
string fnwithExt = "Abc_12_23.png";

```
        string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fnwithExt);
        int indexOf = fn.LastIndexOf('_');
        string part1 = fn.Substring(0, indexOf-1);
        string part2 = fn.Substring(indexOf+1);
        string part3 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fnwithExt);

        string original = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(part1 + "_"+ part2, part3);
```